# How to highlight first item in a list view by default outside onItemClickListener?

Tags: android, android-listview, highlighting

I have a list view. I need to highlight the first item in the list view by default. I referred to this code:

1)

```
listView.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

2)

```
listView.setItemChecked(0,true);
   listView.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

3)

```
listView.setSelection(0);
   listView.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

These codes work fine inside `OnItemClickListener`().... But I want to make the item highlighted after `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` code....

Please help me..........

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have still no answer. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

have you put this on your listview:

```
lisview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
lisview.setSelection(0);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In getView method of your adapter, highlight when position is 0...